# How do I set an alias name in the hosts file?

Tags: windows-xp, hosts, alias

I have a production server, on which three different application are running.  I need to configure aliases for that server, according to which application needs to be accessed by the user.

How do I set an alias name in the hosts file?

Answer (score 11):

For adding a alias name to a server in the hosts file you have to make the following structure:

In the first column you have to add the IP-Address, in the second column the host-name and in the third column you have to add the desired alias-name. Any subsequent columns are alias for that host. In the example's second line the IP-Address 192.168.0.2 is for the server test.server.com and another name for it is test.

For example:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost            test.server.com
192.168.0.2     test.server.com      test
192.168.0.3     another.server.com   another
```

Comment: Default path to hosts file on Windows XP `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Comment: Based on the question I assumed that the threadstarter is knowing where the hosts-file is. Nevertheless thank you for the addendum :-)

Comment: uh, having two identical names
127.0.0.1       localhost            test.server.com
192.168.0.2     test.server.com      test
for differnt IPs can cause headaches... I'll assume a copy&paste error there ;)

Comment: thank u but others not able to connect to alias name.

Comment: Yes, you will need to edit the hosts file on each computer that will use the alias; if you want to make this a global change, you need to use a real DNS server.

Answer (score 5):

Usually, the Syntax is:

```
<<IP>> hostname alias1 alias2
```

example:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost lo loopback
```

I hope it works the same under Windows XP