# Windows hosts file: aliases without explicit IP address?

Tags: windows, networking, dns

I know that you can set up host names in `%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

But it seems you **must** put an IP address at the beginning of the line, which makes it fragile if you really want to resolve a host name.

So you can't put, for instance:

```
mail.google.com   togooglemail
```

...since it doesn't start with an IP address.  You could `ping mail.google.com` and put that IP address in, but you know that's eventually going to let you down.

Is there a way, in this file or elsewhere, achieve this local DNS mapping without explicit IP address?

(FYI, we're working around a field-entry limitation in some legacy software.)

Similar to [this Q](https://superuser.com/questions/41652/how-do-i-set-an-alias-name-in-the-hosts-file).

Comment: "Is there a way, in this file" No. "elsewhere" No, at least built into Windows.

Comment: Run your own DNS server with a fake TLD (example.test) and use CNAME data.

Comment: Any chance there's an easily-configurable open-source package to run such a DNS server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Windows hosts file supports only *ip->name mappings*, it does not support any
other standard DNS record types.

You could try using a plugin in the browser, instead of editing the hosts file,
such as [Redirector](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/redirector/) for Firefox or [Redirector for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redirector/pajiegeliagebegjdhebejdlknciafen).

Otherwise, you could use a local DNS server.
One I have found is the free and simple
[Technitium DNS Server](https://technitium.com/dns/),
but there are many others such as [OpenDNS](https://www.opendns.com/).